# Why do I get a NaN value and the end of my rubiks cube scramble generator when I remove duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I am developing a Rubik cube app for fitbit versa and I run into the problem of removing duplicates from arrays as I get a NaN error when combining the arrays once the duplicates have been removed from the end of the list and it only happens when I splice at the end of the array and I cant figure out the reason why this isnt working

```js
function getScramble(number_of_moves, faces, modifiers, scramble_faces, scramble_modifiers, scramble) {

  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_moves; i++) {
    var sample = faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
    var mod = modifiers[Math.floor(Math.random() * modifiers.length)];
    scramble_faces[i] = sample;
    scramble_modifiers[i] = mod;
    if (scramble_faces[i] == scramble_faces[i - 1]) {
      scramble_faces[i] = faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
    }
  }
  removeDuplicates(scramble_faces, scramble_modifiers)
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_moves - 2; i++) {
    scramble[i] = scramble_faces[i] + scramble_modifiers[i]
  }

  console.log(scramble);

  let demotext = document.getElementById("demotext");
  demotext.text = scramble;
  scramble = [];
  scramble_faces = [];
  scramble_modifiers = [];
}
```

```js
function threebythree() {
  var faces = ["U", "D", "L", "R", "F", "B"];
  var modifiers = ["", "'", "2"];
  var scramble_faces = [];
  var scramble_modifiers = [];
  var scramble = [];
  var number_of_moves = 22;
  let Title1 = document.getElementById("title");
  Title1.text = "3x3"
  getScramble(number_of_moves, faces, modifiers, scramble_faces, scramble_modifiers, scramble, Title1)
}
```

```js
function removeDuplicates(arr, arr2, number_of_moves) {
  var t = 0;
  var new_arr = arr;
  var new_arr2 = arr2;
  for (var i = new_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (new_arr[i] === new_arr[i - 1]) {
      new_arr.splice(i, 1);
      new_arr2.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  arr = new_arr;
  arr2 = new_arr2;
  new_arr = [];
  new_arr2 = [];
  new_arr.pop();
  new_arr2.pop();

  console.log(arr);
  console.log(arr2);
}
```

Comment: seems the code portion for the getScramble function is not complete. Could you please post the complete code portion so we can help to take a look?

Comment: yep just did I realized that, right after I posted it, didnt copy the whole thing

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the problem, but `var new_arr = arr;` doesn't make a copy of the array. Both variables still refer to the same array.

Comment: What's the point of doing `new_arr.pop()` right after you assign an empty array to the variable? There's nothing to remove from the array.

Comment: The new_arr.pop() removes the last thing from the array, I really didn’t need to do this, but I removed it and it doesn’t make a difference, and setting a new array which I can manipulate easier helps clear up ram and helps battery life as it is for a watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lengths of `scramble_faces` and `scramble_modifiers` is initially `number_of_moves`. But after you remove duplicates from them, it can be shorter. But you still use `number_of_moves` in the limit in the next `for` loop. So when you try to add the elements that no longer exist you get `undefined`. `undefined + undefined == NaN`.

You should use the length of one of the arrays instead:

```js
function getScramble(number_of_moves, faces, modifiers, scramble_faces, scramble_modifiers, scramble) {

  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_moves; i++) {
    var sample = faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
    var mod = modifiers[Math.floor(Math.random() * modifiers.length)];
    scramble_faces[i] = sample;
    scramble_modifiers[i] = mod;
    if (scramble_faces[i] == scramble_faces[i - 1]) {
      scramble_faces[i] = faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
    }
  }
  removeDuplicates(scramble_faces, scramble_modifiers)
  for (var i = 0; i < scramble_faces.length - 2; i++) {
    scramble[i] = scramble_faces[i] + scramble_modifiers[i]
  }

  console.log(scramble);

  let demotext = document.getElementById("demotext");
  demotext.text = scramble;
  scramble = [];
  scramble_faces = [];
  scramble_modifiers = [];
}
```